# thymeleaf mapping of object that has an inner object within a form

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, thymeleaf

i have 2 objects one is persisting (product) the other is an an embeddable address (storeWhereLocated), this object persists within product.

i am trying to create a form to persist the product using thymeleaf.

here is the Product entity im trying to persist

```
public class Product {

@Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides(value = {
            @AttributeOverride(name = "addressLine1", column = @Column(name = "address")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "addressLine2", column = @Column(name = "unit")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "city", column = @Column(name = "city")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "state", column = @Column(name = "state")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "zipCode", column = @Column(name = "zip_code"))
    })
    private Address storeWhereLocated;
}
```

this is the Address object no persisting needed here only within product entity

```
@Embeddable
public class Address {

    @NotNull
    @Size(min=2, max = 100)
    private String addressLine1;

    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 50)
    private String addressLine2;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min=2, max = 50)
    private String city;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min= 2, max = 25)
    private String state;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min=1, max = 6)
    private String zipCode;
```

here is the form

```
<form th:action="@{/product/add}" method="post" th:object="${product}"
          enctype="multipart/form-data">

      <input  th:field="*{storeWhereLocated.addressLine1}"/>
      <input  th:field="*{storeWhereLocated.addressLine2}"/>
      <input  th:field="*{storeWhereLocated.city}"/>
      <input  th:field="*{storeWhereLocated.state}"/>
      <input  th:field="*{storeWhereLocated.zipCode}"/> 

</form>
```

[image]

my question is will this work the way i have it or not.  i am trying to read up on it but could not come across anything.

Comment: Why don't you just try it?

Comment: i didn't think it would work.. but it did.. thanks